# I am having trouble upgrading to Neo4j 1.9 to 2.0

Tags: java, macos, neo4j

See the bash scripts - My Java SDK and JRE are upgraded to version 7 - I am stumped.

```
charless-mbp:~ charlesdibsdale$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
charless-mbp:~ charlesdibsdale$ neo4j stop
Instance running via launchd with PID 3196, stopping it...
charless-mbp:~ charlesdibsdale$ neo4j start
WARNING! You are using an unsupported version of the Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dneo4j.ext.udc.source=homebrew
Detected installation in launchd, starting it...
```

See [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove your old installation first from launchd.

So go to the old installation and do `bin/neo4j remove` then your new server should start without problems.